# Input cleared when 'done' button on iOS virtual keyboard touched

Tags: ios, reactjs, input, autofill, virtual-keyboard

My React App has an issue about input and iOS virtual keyboard.

[This is Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P40o.png)

after I got SMS pass code, the code appears on top of keyboard automatically.

1. when I touch outside the keyboard to hide it, the code remains.
   [remain code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z20gd.png)
2. but when I touch 'done' button on right side of keyboard, the code is gone and input cleared. -> problem!

[cleared input img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BsBZ.png)

How can I fix this ?
I think that I can't controll the virtual keyboard and 'done' button directly by using JS.
It works well at Android, but especially not working at iOS.

Here is my testing environment :

- iOS v16.1.1
- device : iPhone SE2
- using Chrome

Help me please :(
I want to keep the value of input when I touch 'done' button(case 2) like when I touch outside the keyboard(case 1).

Here is my code.

```
...

const [verifyNum, setVerifyNum] = useState('');

<input
            placeholder="인증번호 6자리"
            value={verifyNum} 
            onChange={(e) => setVerifyNum(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            maxLength={6}
            inputMode="numeric"
          >
```

I tried `autocomplete="one-time-code"` but it's not worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.